# API de MercadoPago no me toma la tarjeta de pruebas que ofrece en la documentacion

Tags: php, api, mercadopago

Estoy intentando hacer una compra de prueba desde el enlace de producción (habiendole definido antes el sandbox_mode(TRUE)):

```
$mp = new \MP(BASIC_CHECKOUT_CLIENT_ID, BASIC_CHECKOUT_CLIENT_SECRET);
$mp->sandbox_mode(TRUE);
```

pero cuando intento hacer la compra, despues de cargar toda la info, hago click en "Ya hable con visa y me autorizo el pago", y me vuelve a cargar la primer pagina del proceso de pago.

Alguien sabe si esta andando mal el modo sandbox en este punto en particular, o si hay que cargar algun otro dato preciso que no se comenta en la documentacion?

El proceso de pago como me va apareciendo es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Bueno, pude avanzar un poco utilizando un usuario de prueba haciendo lo que se indica aca:
https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/test/test-users/

El problema que tengo ahora es que al intentar terminar la compra me tira un error:

> Una de las partes es un usuario de prueba.

El enlace de compra lo genero usando mis credenciales de checkout básico, y agregando como puse en la pregunta anterior `$mp->sandbox_mode(TRUE)`. ¿Cómo hago para que la compra se le realice a otro usuario de prueba?

Tengo que generar una cuenta vendedor aparte en mercadopago a partir de los datos del usuario de prueba? No encontre nada al respecto en la poco presentable documentación que ofrecen en el sitio de mercadopago

Comment: Entiendo tu pregunta, lo que no entiendo es que quieres hacer.

Comment: Estoy intentando hacer una compra de prueba. Ahora encontre como crear usuarios de prueba y avance un poco (apenas) mas. Ahora intento comprar logueado como el usuario de pruebas, pero me da un error diciendo que uno de los usuarios es de prueba. Supongo que deberia crear un usuario-vendedor/tienda de prueba, pero no aparece mucha documentacion al respecto (deberia tener un client_id, token, etc distinto para este usuario? usar esa info para autenticar desde mi clase mercadopago?)

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente la documentación para developers esta un poco pobre, debes crear otro usuario de prueba para el vendedor, maneja cada uno en un browser diferente por comodidad, y en el del vendedor, debes acceder a sus [credenciales](https://www.mercadopago.com/mlv/account/credentials?type=basic) para indicar sus tokens al crear tu objeto MP. Debes apagar el modo sandbox (no va bien igual) y crear tu preferencia directamente con el init_point. Allí podrás usar tarjetas de prueba o incluso reales sin problema. Suerte.